# personal blog format/layout/framework

Tags: php, blog

I am thinking about dumping my daily stupidity on a blog kind of a thing. Its all technical stuff. No fancy graphics. Some pictures at most.

Can you suggest any framework which is easy to use? I prefer PHP but that its negotiable. It would be great if I could borrow the couple of site layout and tweak them to my need.

Thanks!

Comment: not constructive? really? can I not ask for opinions here? come on.....

Comment: should I try every possible framework and decide myself? yes...that sounds like a *plan*

Comment: You can without big headache try Serendipity, Dotclear, MaxSite CMS, PivotX. All are really good (some better than others) and smart blog-engines. I finished my searches with Serendipity (s9y)

Comment: Thanks @LazyBadger! looking at Serendipity and it looks nice so far. I will update with what I end up using.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress will be the best for you..... you can find good themes on themeforest.net ... and there a lot of plugins available like for seo and syntax highlighting

Comment: Wordpress will be WORST!

Comment: @LazyBadger Why is that ?

Comment: @ArshdeepSingh - personal experience and comparisions: I **used all mentioned** blogs (+some skipped) in real projects